# Reload entire ember app

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an ember app that is just a small part of a larger app. Its being displayed inside a div and surrounded by a html layout created in rails.

I would like to be able to reload the Ember app to its default Index route and reload its data in a callback in some javascript outside ember. I am finding this tough to do. I know that inside and ember controller I can refresh and reload a model but how do I do it when I am in the context of some js run outside ember.

I need to be able to do something like:

```
App.LocationsController.reload()
```

But unfortunately such a function doesn't exist. I I cant figure out how to get "inside" the ember controller. For example from the console in chrome how would I get inside the controller and reload the data (all the locations)? I can App.Router.router.refresh() but it doesnt reload the data.

Comment: Are you using routing in Ember?  Is it a single route, multiple routes? Which route do you want to change, what does it look like?

Comment: Hi, there is just one route, called App.ContactInformationRoute.